Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted - While playing video only
My Linux Mint system has issues suspending. If there is video playing in a browser, that system can't suspend. If I close that tab with the video. It can suspend. That sounds like some weird DRM type nonsense.
I've got this message in logs:
Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7

The suspend command from terminal isn't working and the button in Cinnamon is simply not there. I don't want to disable secure boot, my dual boot to Windows would probably not like that.
What is going on here? How do I stop it? I've read things about encrypted swap, but my system doesn't even have a swap partition. I understand it writes system state to disk, could it be I have to little space on disk or something? Or is it suspending to RAM?
This is my config
rider@Ruby-Desktop:~$ inxi -Fxxxmprz
System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-44-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 13.2.0
    clocksource: tsc
  Desktop: Cinnamon v: 6.2.9 tk: GTK v: 3.24.41 wm: Muffin v: 6.2.0 vt: 7
    dm: LightDM v: 1.30.0 Distro: Linux Mint 22 Wilma base: Ubuntu 24.04 noble
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: Micro-Star model: MAG B550M MORTAR (MS-7C94) v: 1.0
    serial: <superuser required> uuid: <superuser required> UEFI: American
    Megatrends LLC. v: 1.E0 date: 03/27/2023
Memory:
  System RAM: total: 64 GiB available: 62.72 GiB used: 4.47 GiB (7.1%)
  Message: For most reliable report, use superuser + dmidecode.
  Array-1: capacity: 128 GiB slots: 4 modules: 4 EC: None
    max-module-size: 32 GiB note: est.
  Device-1: Channel-A DIMM 0 type: DDR4 detail: synchronous unbuffered
    (unregistered) size: 16 GiB speed: 2133 MT/s volts: 1 note: check
    width (bits): data: 64 total: 64 manufacturer: N/A
    part-no: CP16G4DFRA32A.M8FF serial: <filter>
  Device-2: Channel-A DIMM 1 type: DDR4 detail: synchronous unbuffered
    (unregistered) size: 16 GiB speed: 2133 MT/s volts: 1 note: check
    width (bits): data: 64 total: 64 manufacturer: Crucial
    part-no: BLS16G4D30AESC.M16FE serial: <filter>
  Device-3: Channel-B DIMM 0 type: DDR4 detail: synchronous unbuffered
    (unregistered) size: 16 GiB speed: 2133 MT/s volts: 1 note: check
    width (bits): data: 64 total: 64 manufacturer: N/A
    part-no: CP16G4DFRA32A.M8FF serial: <filter>
  Device-4: Channel-B DIMM 1 type: DDR4 detail: synchronous unbuffered
    (unregistered) size: 16 GiB speed: 2133 MT/s volts: 1 note: check
    width (bits): data: 64 total: 64 manufacturer: Corsair
    part-no: CMK16GX4M1B3000C15 serial: N/A
CPU:
  Info: 12-core model: AMD Ryzen 9 5900X bits: 64 type: MT MCP smt: enabled
    arch: Zen 3+ rev: 2 cache: L1: 768 KiB L2: 6 MiB L3: 64 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 2349 high: 3700 min/max: 2200/4950 boost: enabled cores:
    1: 2241 2: 2200 3: 2200 4: 2200 5: 2200 6: 2200 7: 2879 8: 2200 9: 2200
    10: 2200 11: 2200 12: 3700 13: 2200 14: 2200 15: 2200 16: 2200 17: 2200
    18: 2200 19: 2200 20: 2200 21: 2200 22: 2880 23: 2880 24: 2200
    bogomips: 177588
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 sse4a ssse3 svm
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 [GeForce GTX 1080] driver: nvidia v: 535.183.01
    arch: Pascal pcie: speed: 2.5 GT/s lanes: 16 ports: active: none
    off: DP-1,HDMI-A-1 empty: DP-2,DP-3,DVI-D-1 bus-ID: 2b:00.0
    chip-ID: 10de:1b80 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: Logitech Logi Webcam C920e driver: uvcvideo type: USB rev: 2.0
    speed: 480 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-2:3 chip-ID: 046d:08b6 class-ID: 0e02
    serial: <filter>
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 21.1.11 with: Xwayland v: 23.2.6 driver: X:
    loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa
    gpu: nvidia,nvidia-nvswitch display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 4480x1440 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1185x381mm (46.65x15.00")
    s-diag: 1245mm (49.01")
  Monitor-1: DP-0 pos: primary,left res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109
    size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 685mm (26.97") modes: N/A
  Monitor-2: HDMI-0 pos: right res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 102
    size: 480x270mm (18.9x10.63") diag: 551mm (21.68") modes: N/A
  API: EGL Message: No EGL data available.
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6.0 vendor: nvidia v: 535.183.01 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1080/PCIe/SSE2
Audio:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GP104 High Definition Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16 bus-ID: 2b:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10f0
    class-ID: 0403
  Device-2: AMD Starship/Matisse HD Audio vendor: Micro-Star MSI
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 16 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 2d:00.4 chip-ID: 1022:1487 class-ID: 0403
  Device-3: Texas Instruments PCM2902 Audio Codec
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid type: USB rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 3-1:2 chip-ID: 08bb:2902 class-ID: 0300
  API: ALSA v: k6.8.0-44-generic status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 1.0.5 status: active with: 1: pipewire-pulse
    status: active 2: wireplumber status: active
  Server-2: PulseAudio v: 16.1 status: off (using pipewire-pulse)
Network:
  Device-1: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE vendor: Micro-Star MSI driver: r8169
    v: kernel pcie: speed: 5 GT/s lanes: 1 port: f000 bus-ID: 2a:00.0
    chip-ID: 10ec:8125 class-ID: 0200
  IF: enp42s0 state: up speed: 1000 Mbps duplex: full mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode) driver: btusb
    v: 0.8 type: USB rev: 2.0 speed: 12 Mb/s lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-7.1:6
    chip-ID: 0a12:0001 class-ID: e001
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 0 state: up address: <filter> bt-v: 4.0
    lmp-v: 6 sub-v: 22bb hci-v: 6 rev: 22bb class-ID: 7c0104
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 1.36 TiB used: 92.02 GiB (6.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 960 EVO 250GB
    size: 232.89 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter>
    fw-rev: 3B7QCXE7 temp: 34.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-2: /dev/nvme1n1 vendor: Samsung model: SSD 980 1TB size: 931.51 GiB
    speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 2B4QFXO7
    temp: 45.9 C scheme: GPT
  ID-3: /dev/sda vendor: Samsung model: SSD 850 EVO 250GB size: 232.89 GiB
    speed: 6.0 Gb/s tech: SSD serial: <filter> fw-rev: 2B6Q scheme: MBR
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 125.24 GiB used: 91.99 GiB (73.5%) fs: ext4
    dev: /dev/nvme1n1p4
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 96 MiB used: 31.4 MiB (32.7%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/nvme0n1p1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 52.5 C mobo: N/A gpu: nvidia temp: 50 C
  Fan Speeds (rpm): N/A gpu: nvidia fan: 39%
Repos:
  Packages: 2436 pm: dpkg pkgs: 2420 pm: flatpak pkgs: 12 pm: snap pkgs: 4
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.asc] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu noble stable
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list
    1: deb [arch=amd64] https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
    1: deb https://mirrors.evoluso.com/linuxmint-packages/linuxmint-packages wilma main upstream import backport
    2: deb http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu noble main restricted universe multiverse
    3: deb http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu noble-updates main restricted universe multiverse
    4: deb http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/os/linux/ubuntu noble-backports main restricted universe multiverse
    5: deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ noble-security main restricted universe multiverse
Info:
  Processes: 490 Power: uptime: 6h 49m states: freeze,mem suspend: deep
    wakeups: 0 hibernate: disabled Init: systemd v: 255 target: graphical (5)
    default: graphical
  Compilers: gcc: 13.2.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.21 running-in: gnome-terminal
    inxi: 3.3.34

